# mpld3 tooltips fails when changing XTick locations

Tags: python, matplotlib, tooltip, mpld3

I'm having a bit of trouble with the following run in an ipython notebook on mac osx with python 3.3:

```
import mpld3
from mpld3 import plugins
mpld3.enable_notebook()

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
points = plt.scatter([0,3,5, 9], [2,4,6, 8])
labels= ['a', 'b', 'c']
#ax.xaxis.set_ticks([2,4])
tooltip = plugins.PointHTMLTooltip(points, labels,
                                   voffset=10, hoffset=10)
plugins.connect(fig, tooltip)
mpld3.display()
```

Works great. However, if I uncomment out:

```
ax.xaxis.set_ticks([2,4])
```

It crashes with the error: TypeError: 2 is not JSON serializable

Is this a bug? Is there a work around?

Thanks!

Comment: Apparently, the function wants a json object, you give it a list, try to pass json.dumps([2,4]) as parameter.

Comment: changing it to: ax.xaxis.set_ticks(json.dumps([2,4]) ) crashes with the error message: TypeError: unorderable types: numpy.ndarray() < str()

Answer (score 0):

This is [a bug](https://github.com/jakevdp/mpld3/issues/277), thanks for identifying it.  The work around is to use `plt.xticks` and provide labels for the ticks explicitly:

```
plt.xticks([2,4], [2,4])
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out! It will definitely help me out in something I'm trying out. I would love to try to improve this aspect of mpld3 at some point.